# Excel groups not able to be sorted?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with sport, player, and player rating. I then grouped it to expand and collapse by sport:

[image: 1]

I now want to collapse to subtotal rows (blue) and sort by descending rating (avg of player rating by sport)

[image: 2]

but now when I expand the grouping hierarchy, it doesn't show the players underneath the sport, it's jumbled:

[image: 3]

What am i missing, is this possible to sort in excel when you group things like I have here?

I tried creating a ranking index based on subtotal avg rating, but that did not work when I tried sorting on that index column either

Comment: No, it's not possible to sort when you use groupings. Wouldn't a pivot table give you what you want?

Comment: here's a formula that would do it based on the name `=LET(zData,FILTER(A:C,IF(A:A<>"",ROW(A:A)>1)),icol,FILTER(zData,INDEX(zData,,2)="TOTAL"),eScore,VLOOKUP(INDEX(zData,,1),INDEX(icol,,1),3,FALSE),sVale,HSTACK(zData, eScore),TAKE(SORT(sVale,4,-1),,3))` probably not what you wan though.